# Octopress: How to insert a logo as a blog title?

Tags: octopress

I don't like the font of my blog title, I tried different fonts, none are working the way I want, so I prepared a png logo, served via imgur, and I want to insert it as my blog title instead of the default title.

How to do so? Which files to edit? the header.html? I just want to know what file to edit, that's all

Comment: I’ve used this to put a picture in the header a couple of times: http://blog.bigdinosaur.org/changing-octopresss-header/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would like to give you the answer, consider the following method:

Use firebug to find out the html and css of your title.

In Chrome you can right click on the page then "Inspect Element".

On the menu that opens on the left side there is a little magnifying glass (to the left of "Elements"). Click on that and then an element on your page.

On the bottom menu you can see the html and on the right side you can see the CSS.

You can type anything into the CSS "Styles" window to preview any changes that you make.

You can also a link of the file for the element you are inspecting.